# Realm fetching objects on background thread and pass to main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, realm

I want to fetch large amount of objects on the background thread, however i cannot pass them to the main thread, as i get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread'
```

fetch code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    //Background Thread
    RLMRealm * realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    self.allObjectsRLMResult = [MyClass allObjectsInRealm:realm];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        // use self.allObjects and do stuff on main thread

    });

});
```

**How to perform a fetch on the background and pass the object to the main thread so there is minimal performance impact**

I could get the primary keys, and then refetch on the main thread, but this will be the same performance (possibly even slower) as fetching them directly

Answer (score 6):

Joe from Realm here. Currently what you described (getting primary keys) is the best way to do it. We are aware of this and have been looking into a thread handover solution but for now that will be the best way for you to get your objects.

Comment: Thanks guys... the method with handing over the primary keys is in the case of allObjects less performant, than requesting allObjects directly... currently we have like 3000 objects, which takes around 1-2 secs to load on iPhone 5s (these objects have only like 5 string properties)

Comment: How long is it taking requesting allObjects directly, 1-2secs?

Comment: would love to see this implemented.. running into this issue right now where fetching on main thread and processing data before loading is not performant..

Comment: @yoshyosh I'm struggling with performance issues, when getting the IDs of the fetched objects. I don't know if this is the best approach but I'm retrieving them like this (swift): `let objectIds = listOfResults.flatMap({ $0["objectId"] })`. Any other advices?

Comment: How are you creating `listOfResults` and what are you trying to do? Are you creating an array of objectId's to then pass to the main thread?